# Matplotlib how to scale the x axis by a factor of 2

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot something in matplotlib and I want the x axis to have the values.
0 2 4 8 16 32 64 256

plt.xticks Doesn't work because it doesn't evenly scale the x axis. It does what is in the imagine below.

```
plt.xticks([0, 2, 4 ,8 ,16 ,32, 64, 128, 256])
```

[image]

Is there anyway to get the imagine to look like this imagine below?

[image]

Where the numbers are even spaced along the bottom like this?

Comment: That wouldn't scale them by a factor of 2, while equally spaced.

Comment: From what im reading i guess its not possible, does anyone know a library that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
axis = fig.add_subplot()
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([0, 2, 4 ,8 ,16 ,32, 64, 128, 256])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([0, 2, 4 ,8 ,16 ,32, 64, 128, 256])
    
ax.plot(x)
plt.show
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want matplotlib to space the values evenly and not according to the numerical values you need to give them as text and not as numbers.
The following code gives a straight line when x is given as text and a curve when x is given as numerical values.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# numerical values, spacing according to value, gives a curve
x = np.array([2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]) 

# text values, spaced evenly, gives a straight line
x = np.array(['2','4','8','16','32','64','128','256'])

y = np.arange(1,9)
plt.title("Matplotlib demo")
plt.xlabel("x axis")
plt.ylabel("y axis")
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```